# Angular: Is there a way to override ngOnInit using class decorators?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-decorator

I am trying to override the ngOnInit method for many of my components using a decorator.

I've created a decorator at decorators/visibilityTracked.decorator.ts:

```js
export function VisibilityTracked(component : availableComponents): ClassDecorator {
  return function ( target : any ) {
    const ngOnInit = target.prototype.ngOnInit;
    target.prototype.ngOnInit = function ( ...args ) {
      // my custom logic here
      console.log('custom_logic');
      ngOnInit.apply(this, args);
    }
  }
}
```

Then I apply the decorator on my component. To make sure it executes the extended ngOnInit, I `console.log()` it.

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
@VisibilityTracked(availableComponents.ROOM_MENU)
export class menuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    ngOnInit() {
      // component logic
      console.log('component_logic');
      console.log(this.ngOnInit);
      ...
    }
}
```

console output:

```
---
component logic
---
ƒ (...args) {
            console.log('custom_logic');
            ngOnInit.apply(this, args);
        }
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju2fJ.png)

seems like the decorator-added logic of ngOnInit IS NOT EXECUTED, but the ngOnInit itself has changed.

What's wrong with this method. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Can you give more context as to why you want to override ngOnInit? The route your taking could more than likely work but I am trying to figure out what the main goal actually is.

Comment: The main goal is to keep track of the loaded components (I want to add some logic where I need to know what components are loaded on the page). This is easy to achieve if I just call a dedicated service in ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy